# How to invoke Grails action and parse its json result?

Tags: json, grails

I have a filter that is filtering for some actions. In case this is a required action I need to render it and see its response (json). how could I invoke it and see if the response contains errors?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the `afterView`?

> afterView - Executed after view rendering. Takes an Exception as an
>   argument which will be non-null if an exception occurs during
>   processing. Note: this Closure is called before the layout is applied

More on the [docs](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/single.html#filters).